# How To Replace UITableView With Image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UITableView that is blank be default until the user edits and adds data to it.  I want to show an image with instructions that is shown until the user edits it.

The size of the picture is so it fits under perfectly between the nav bar and the tab bar.

Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `removeFromSuperview` to remove `UITableView` from super view then add your `UIImageView`.

Use the below code :

```
-(void) NeedView:(BOOL) aIsImageView
{
    if(aIsImageView)
    {
        [m_TableView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubviews:m_ImageView];
    }
    else 
    {
        [m_ImageView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubviews:m_TableView];
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I go about positioning the image then?  Do I create another view in the NIB and add a UIImage in there?  I think doing it programmatically would be easier.

Comment: @Faisal :go programmatically will be easier, let me know if you stuck in btw.

Comment: And is m_TableView the name of the file I am using?  So RoutineTableViewController for RoutineTableViewController.h?

Comment: @Faisal: Declare both  m_TableView and m_ImageView in .h file of your RoutineTableViewController eg.  UITableView* m_TableView; and UIImageView* m_ImageView,then create them in init function of RoutineTableViewController.m

Comment: Ok, so currently the table view I am working with is of class UITableViewController.  So Should I change it to UIViewController instead then add the table view and image view objects to it?

Comment: @Faisal: YES, i would suggest you change to UIViewController,

Answer (score 1):

Create a UIView add your UITableView as a subview.  Create a UIImageView with your instructions image and add it as a subView as well. Position the instructions imageView behind the the tableView. In ViewWillAppear add a test for empty table and hide the table based on that check. If you allow users to delete rows you will also have to check for empty table in:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
        // do delete
        // get count of rows in UITableView and hide table if it's empty
    }
...
```

Comment: Ok thanks Kirby, I think your method would be better than Jhaliya's because if a user deletes their table entries, it would be nice for the image to show up again.  Could you perhaps provide more detail on what you commented out? To get count would I just use a boolean and ask if index or [table count] = 0?

Comment: Well that depends on if you table is grouped or plain. If it's just a plain table with one section you can get the row count from your datasource by calling numberOfRowsInSection with zero for section.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that difficult to achieve, you just can show the image you want to show with the specified frame (may be frame(0, 44, 320, 392)). and check for the table rows(actually the count of array that u are using to show in table) if it is nonzero just show the image and show the table otherwise.

try this concept and come back with any problem or query..