# Handling an empty Table view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

What I am trying to do is pretty simple, I just want to display some message to the user that there are no entries in this table, rather than just displaying a blank page.  An ideal example is in the app store, if you search for something, but get no results, it just displays in the middle of the page "No Matches".

I've looked at a few solutions, and decided that the one i like best is  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400342/how-to-replace-uitableview-with-image)  But theres a few little problems with it:

1) I can still drag around the image as if it was just a very large cell in the tableview

2) when I try to re-add the tableview to the tabelviewcontroller's view, I seem to get some kind of infinite recursion that eventually crashes

Anyone know a simpler way to do this?  Or how I can resolve my current issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan F it's very easy all you need to do is the following:

- if there is no data in your source, add one object like `No Data Found`
- Set a flag like `BOOL bNoDataFound = YES`
- in `CellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate check your flag is YES fill the only cell with your text that you set before

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, not quite exactly the solution I was looking for, but it does work.

Answer (score 4):

Don't remove the tableView, just add an UIView with your message (i.e. UIImageView) on top off it. It only needs to be big enough to cover the tableView. Place something like 
 at the appropriate place in your UITableViewController:

```
if (results == 0) {
     [self.view addSubview:noResultsView];
}
```

Comment: That is what im doing now, but it has the scrolling problem

Comment: you have to place it in front (above) your table view, not inside it. (wow this is an old question)